# Facebook PHP - SDK - timeline posting not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to post on Facebook user's timeline using Facebook's PHP SDK. The postFacebook() method contains the code to post to the user's timeline. My code works fine for Facebook login but Facebook posting does not works.

There will be a custom composer for the message that is to be filled by the user. That message from the user will be posted on to the user's timeline. I had already got my Facebook app approved to obtain 'publish_actions' permission with the access token.

```
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx', 'yyy' );
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'url' );
        if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
          $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
          try {
            if ( !$session->validate() ) {
              $session = null;
            }
          } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            $session = null;
          }
        }  
        if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
          try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
          } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
            print_r( $ex );
          } catch( Exception $ex ) {
            print_r( $ex );
          }
        }
        if ( isset( $session ) ) {
          $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
          $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
          $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
          $response = $request->execute();
          $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
          postFacebook();
          echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>'; 
          echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'url' ) . '">Logout</a>'; 
        } else {
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,publish_actions'));
          header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
        }

        function postFacebook(){
            $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
            try {

              if(isset($_SESSION['event_website'])){
                $request = new FacebookRequest(
                              $session,
                              'POST',
                              '/me/feed',
                              array (
                                'message' => $_SESSION['event_message'],
                                'link' => "http://www." . $_SESSION['event_website'] . ".xxx.com"
                              )
                            );
              } else {
                $request = new FacebookRequest(
                              $session,
                              'POST',
                              '/me/feed',
                              array (
                                'message' => $_SESSION['event_message']
                              )
                            );
              }       
            } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error too.

Comment: Make a var_dump of the API response.